# Error en la instalación de SQL Server 2019 Developer

Tags: sql-server

Al intentar instalar SQL Server 2019 Developer me sale el siguiente error y me impide instalarlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anteriormente tenía instalado la versión de 2016 pero la he desinstalado completamente, incluso he utilizado programas de tipo cleaner y sigue saliendo el mismo error. Me comentaron desde Microsoft que creando un nuevo usuario con rol de administrador se solventaría el problema pero persiste. No se como eliminar el polybase para poder instalar el 2019.

Comment: ¡Qué porquería son los instaladores de Microsoft! Puf, déjame ver si hay algo que se pueda hacer (y la opción de crear un nuevo usuario es básicamente la opción nuclear, _tener todo limpio y ahí seguro funciona_).

Comment: Justo eso hice. He creado un nuevo usuario y he intentado volverlo a instalar pero me da el mismo problema.

Comment: A pesar de ser un MS lover, tengo que estar de acuerdo con Alfabravo. SQLServer, VisualStudio y varias otras herramientas se *'encarnan'* en el sistema operativo y es casi imposible desinstalarlas sin dañar irremediablemente algo. Qué puedes hacer? Iniciar tu viaje de peregrinación a través de todos los foros de Microsoft, lograr la desinstalación limpia y volver consagrado como un maestro; o re-instalas tu sistema operativo, como lo hacemos todos los demás simples mortales.

Comment: pregunta de novato: al reinstalar el SO perderia las licencias de windows y office??

Comment: No lo sé. Yo siempre guardo una copia de mis licencias. PERO, puedes investigar y nos cuentas ;)

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución a este problema es deshabilitar la opción del Servicio de Consultas de PolyBase para bases de datos externos durante el proceso de selección de la selección de características.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera te permitirá crear una nueva instancia con un nombre nuevo en la configuración de la instancia siguiendo las reglas de Microsoft sobre Nombres e ID de instancias

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera te permitirá seguir la instalación sin problemas.